# Issue with If keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have question about use of if in Robot Framework

I am trying below thing but it is not working. Need some help.

```
[Arguments]    ${device}
Run Keyword if ${device} is in @{device_list}
do this................
then do this...............
Run Keyword if ${device} is in @{server_list}
do this................
then do this...............
Run Keyword Unless ${device} is in @{router_list}
do this................
then do this...............
```

FYI assume 
    device_list=[a,b,c]
    server_list=[s,d,f]
    router_list=[g,h,j]
and I am using for loop to get device value from different  list in some part of my code and based on the device value which I will get from different list I want to run some part of code.

How I can accomplish this? Can any one please share their idea to implement this in robot framework?
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$` rather than `@` when referencing the list as an object.

If you are using robot framework 2.9 or later you can omit the curly braces in an expression, and the variables will be treated as python variables of the same name. This is documented in the section [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the documentation for the library [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html).

If you want to  run multiple steps when the condition is true, you must use [run keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords) inside the condition.

Here is a complete working example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{device_list}    one  two  three  four
${device}         two

*** Keywords ***
Do something
    log    do something was called

Do something else
    log    do something else was called

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    run keyword if    $device in $device_list
    ...  Run keywords
    ...  Do something
    ...  AND
    ...  Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Library Collections

${res}=    List Should Contain Value    ${device}    @{device_list}
Run Keyword If    ${res}   Do This
Run Keyword Unless    ${res}   Do That
```

I did not actually run it, but that's how I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks For answer. But i have three condition like  and how have mentioned for two condition. Do you have any ides about how can I run this for three condition. And I am also looking for something like if first condition not true then ignore it and run then second and if second condition not true then ignore it/ or error and run the third condition and if the third condition not thru then ignore it.  How can I accomplish this. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I obviously misunderstood the main point in your question, but I think @Bryan answered it very well.